# Where simplexml_load_file of PHP function locate data in memory

Tags: php, xml, memory, simplexml, ram

I am loading XML file by simplexml_load_file() in PHP script. XML file has 50MB size. Before and after the function is get_memory_usage() witch returns the same values. I see that the process is locating about 400MB in RAM. So, where is it located? I need to clear it before the scripts going die.

```
function mem() {
    echo round(memory_get_peak_usage()/1024/1024, 2) . 'MB' . PHP_EOL;
}

mem();

$xml = simplexml_load_file("trips.xml");
mem();

unset($xml);

mem();
```

Why mem(); everytime prints 0.25M but process has 400MB? How  can i clear memory before scripts going down?

Comment: It's located in PHP memory! Where else do you expect it to be? Loading the file using simplexml parses the data from that file it into a tree of XML objects, so filesize and memory usage aren't a direct correlation.

Comment: And you can clear it by using `unset($xml);`

Comment: i have no idea, so could you explain me why unset($xml) does not release space in memory

Comment: If you have problems with memory limits in PHP when working with XML files, then use a pull parser like [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php) instead of SimpleXML

Comment: no i can't, unset does not work in this case... please check it and answer then

Comment: So reading from your coments, the question should really be why `unset()` doesn't work, and I can't answer that in this case because your code shows no evidence of your even using unset()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933365/php-simplexml-large-file-no-extra-memory-usage